# One to Many Relationship - Laravel & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my application, Users can have many products. Now, i am trying to display the users phone number for a every displayed products.

In my products table, there is a column `user_id` for the respective users.
This is how my model looks like

**User Model**

```
public function products()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('Models\Database\User','user_id');    
}
```

**Product Model**

class Product extends BaseModel
{

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id','type', 'name', 'slug', 'sku', 'description',
    'status', 'in_stock', 'track_stock', 'qty', 'is_taxable', 'page_title', 'page_description'];

 // protected $guarded = ['id'];

public static function getCollection()
{
    $model = new static;
    $products = $model->all();
    $productCollection = new ProductCollection();
    $productCollection->setCollection($products);
    return $productCollection;
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\Models\Database\Product');
    //->withTimestamps();
}



public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}

public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductPrice::class);
}









public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}

public function users()
{
      return $this->hasMany('Models\Database\Product');
}
```

And in my view, this is how i try to get the respective user's phone number

```
<p>{{$product->users->phone}}</p>
```

But i get an error like

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'products.product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products`
>   where `products`.`product_id` = 1 and `products`.`product_id` is not
>   null)

Comment: show your product model code

Comment: Remove `'user_id'` in User model's belongsTo relationship and then try!

Comment: @SapneshNaik, check my update please

Comment: @HirenGohel, i just tried that but same results

Comment: Add `user_id` in product's belongsTo relationship like this: `public function user()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('Models\Database\User','user_id');    
}
` and then use `<p>{{$product->user->phone}}</p>` in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

**User Model**

```
public function products()
{
      return $this->hasMany('Models\Database\Product');    
}
```

**Product Model**

```
public function user()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('Models\Database\User');
}
```

In your blade:

```
{{ $product->user->phone }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got your relationship models inverted,

change them:

**In your User model:**

```
public function products()
{
      return $this->hasMany('Models\Database\Product');
}
```

**In your Product model:**

```
public function user()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('Models\Database\User','user_id');    
}
```

**And then you could access the properties like:**

```
<p>{{$product->user->phone}}</p>
```

Link to the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)